# Troubleshooting about user groups and usb devices in virtualbox

Tags: usb, virtualbox, user-groups

While accessing to usb devices in virtualbox I've found that usb devices aren't available, so I've checked user groups for vboxusers and found this:

```
kike@ubuntu:~$ id
uid=1001(kike) gid=1001(kike) grupos=1001(kike)
kike@ubuntu:~$ groups kike
kike : kike adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare libvirtd kvm vboxusers libvirtd
kike@ubuntu:~$ man id
kike@ubuntu:~$ id kike
uid=1001(kike) gid=1001(kike) grupos=1001(kike),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),110(lpadmin),125(sambashare),127(libvirtd),128(kvm),1002(vboxusers),127(libvirtd)
kike@ubuntu:~$ virtualbox
kike@ubuntu:~$ su kike
Contraseña: 
kike@ubuntu:~$ id
uid=1001(kike) gid=1001(kike) grupos=1001(kike),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),110(lpadmin),125(sambashare),127(libvirtd),128(kvm),1002(vboxusers)
kike@ubuntu:~$ virtualbox
```

The first invocation of virtualbox doesn't show any usb device available, while the latter everything is right.

Can someone explain me this behaviour or how can I check and revert it?

Would greatly appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Duplicate of [Linux: groups vs. groups username](https://superuser.com/questions/416374/linux-groups-vs-groups-username) and of [Why is the output from \`groups\` different from \`groups user\`](https://superuser.com/questions/294650/why-is-the-output-from-groups-different-from-groups-user-if-im-currently-log)

Comment: Thanks a lot.
I'm not sure if editing the question for clarification is needed.
Differences between both commands' (_groups/id -Gn_ with or without nickname) output can be found, but here I get different outputs with the same command (id) before and after _su_ command. So reading that links I understand a bit more about why this is happening, but I'm not sure to know where to start checking to mend it.
Please, can you reconsider if it's duplicated or not?